# Golang - Add int to end of byte array

Tags: go

I am trying to add an int to the end of a byte array in Golang.
This is my current code:

```
nameLengthBytes := []byte{32, 32}
nameLength := len(name)
```

The **nameLengthBytes** creates 2 spaces, and what I'm looking for is a way to add the **nameLength** to the end of the **nameLengthBytes**.

*Examples:*
if name length is 7, I want the array to be: {32, 55}
If name length is 12, I want the array to be {49, 50}

The problem is that sometimes the name is shorter than 10 so I need to fill up with a leading zero.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? How did you try to add leading zeros? What causes problems?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to mention that.  I did not add any code regarding adding the number because all my attempts failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a space-padded ascii representation of a number as bytes? `fmt.Sprintf` produces a string, which you can then convert to bytes.

Here's some code, or [run it on the playground.](http://play.golang.org/p/WVNe4QsNMH)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    bs := []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%2d", 7))
    fmt.Println(bs)
}
```